# Не принимает cookie в iframe (Chrome Safari)

Tags: jquery, php, html

Возникла необходимость подключить партнерский магазин через фрейм. но выяснилось что таким образом куки не сохраняются. но если открыть сайт в полном окне, то потом в айфрейме корректно запоминается состояние сессии и корзины.

Что делать? как можно заставить браузер принимать куки в фрейме.

Тестил только в хроме и сафари, но думаю и в других браузерах видимо есть ограничения. как быть?!
Читал на хабре про способ с отправкой формы jquery (от января 2011 года) но походу не работает уже. мол браузеры специально не дают передавать куки через фреймы мол изза того чтоб не палили за юзером.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гугл великая вещь, я даже до конца страницы не до листал, а ответ был найден. Из форума:

Для этого нужно сначала разрешить iframe передавать куки(по умолчанию куки во фрейме блокируются многими браузами
 Для этого 1. Создаём пустой iframe и переадресуем в iframe с главной текущего сайта ответ от отправки незначительной формы с главной страницы, http://htmlbook.ru/html/form (*см тег target)
И затем можно уже менять скриптом внутри фрейма адрес, - на адрес нашего второго сайта,* куки должны прилипнуть и отправить из фрейма мелкую форму(дабы передать куки), форму отправляем скриптом при наличии определенного адреса, вызванной страницы во фрейме